# Papers on time it takes to reach market equilibrium?

Tags: reference-request, competitive-equilibrium

Are there any models which calculate the time (i.e. minutes, hours, days ect.) it takes for equilibrium to occur? I.e how long it takes for market forces to settle.

Comment: Given that you have tagged this general equilibrium, are you asking about a case where initially there is equilibrium in all markets, then there is a single disturbance or shock, and then with no further disturbance the economy settles to a new equilibrium?  If so this seems extremely hypothetical as disturbances somewhere in an economy will be frequent.  The scenario of settling to equilibrium seems more applicable to a single market.

Comment: @AdamBailey My question is more focused on a single market. Changing tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the famous [Cobweb model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_model). Starting from a situation of equilibrium, it analyses the effect of a shock, and how long it takes to reach the equilibrium, which depends entirely on the elasticities (or slopes) of demand and supply. Thus, by estimating empirically such elasticities **for a given period** (e.g. year), you can predict/forecast how many periods (e.g. years) it will take the market to settle after a shock. (Strictly speaking, it is infinity, but you just need to select a threshold or margin of error to consider the market in equilibrium)

$\hskip4cm$ [image]

(Source of image [here](http://masters.donntu.org/2010/fknt/mospan/diss/indexe.htm))

A huge literature exploded after the original paper, so if you google Cobweb models you get tons of hits. A very good treatment of this model can be found in [Waugh (1964)](https://academic.oup.com/ajae/article-abstract/46/4/732/89790/Cobweb-Models?redirectedFrom=fulltext). He extends the simple model to multiple markets.

Comment: Gif seems to stop after a while or its just me?